# Creating new array from existing arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I'm trying to create a new array containing values from pre-existing arrays.

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
    0 => 101,
    1 => 102,
    2 => 121,
    3 => 231,
    4 => 232,
    5 => 233
);

$array2 = array(
    0 => 58,
    1 => 98,
    2 => 45,
    3 => 48,
    4 => 45,
    5 => 85
);

$result = array();
```

Notice that the first element is from `$array1`, second element from `$array2` and so on.

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how you can achieve this:

```
    $array = array(4,5,6);
    $array2 = array(8,9,0,12,44,);
    $count1 = count($array);
    $count2 = count($array2);
    $count = ($count1 > $count2) ? $count1 : $count2;
    $rez = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($i < $count1) {
           $rez[] = $array[$i];
        } 
        if ($i < $count2) {
           $rez[] = $array2[$i];
        }


    }

var_dump($rez);
```

Result will be an array

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
  [1]=>
  int(8)
  [2]=>
  int(5)
  [3]=>
  int(9)
  [4]=>
  int(6)
  [5]=>
  int(0)
  [6]=>
  int(12)
  [7]=>
  int(44)
}
```

but if you need to save empty values you can remove
this checks `if ($i < $count2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `for` or `foreach` loops (in case `$array1` and `$array2` have the same number of elements with the same indexes):

```
$result = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++){
  $result[] = $array1[$i];
  $result[] = $array2[$i];
}
```

`[]` gives you a feature to *not specify the index*, so you can just push them one by one from each array to the result array.

#### [Example with for loop](https://eval.in/243892)

#### [Example with foreach loop](https://eval.in/243894)

There is also a more straightforward way to do it, without worrying about lost indexes and elements :

```
$i = 0;

foreach($array1 as $v){
  $result[$i] = $v;
  $i = $i+2;
}

$i = 1;

foreach($array2 as $v){
  $result[$i] = $v;
  $i = $i+2;
}

ksort($result);
```

#### [Example](https://eval.in/243905)

It looks a bit cumbersome, so you can write a function to make it more elegant :

```
function build_array(&$array, $input, $counter){
   foreach($input as $v){
      $array[$counter] = $v;
      $counter = $counter+2;
   }
}

build_array($result, $array1, 0);
build_array($result, $array2, 1);
ksort($result);
```

#### [Example](https://eval.in/243904)